# Are there built in functions to perform a geometric transform to rotate a set of points around an arbitrary point?

Tags: geometry, vector, geometric-transform

I have a list of points `{{4,5},{6,7},{9,8},...}` in two-dimensions.  I'd like to rotate these points some number of degrees $\theta$ around an arbitrary anchor point in a two-dimensional plane, and recover the transformed point list.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?  How about for three-dimensional rotations around an arbitrary point?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation center? is is very very easy to find in documentation and this question shows no research effort :/

Comment: @Kuba I've looked at Rotate, GeometricTransform, etc. but they all seem to apply to rotating graphical objects as opposed to point sets.

Comment: If type in "rotation" the second result is `RotationTransform`. It is always good idea to check *related* links at the bottom of each documentation page because `RotationTranform` appears for example in `Rotate` page.

Comment: @Kuba Is it necessary for me to manually enter in and multiply each point by the appropriate rotation matrix?  Shouldn't there be a function that takes the point set, a rotation anchor, and then some rotation parameter?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `RotationTransform[angle \[Degree], anchor] /@ set`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationTransform.html) is what you are looking for.

```
data = {{4, 5}, {6, 7}, {9, 8}};
r[angle_?NumericQ, pivot:{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] = RotationTransform[angle Degree, pivot];
r[45, {1, 1}] /@ data // N
```

> ```
> {{0.292893, 5.94975}, {0.292893, 8.77817}, {1.70711, 11.6066}}
> ```

#### Update

As Carl Woll points out in his comment below, the transformation function returned by `RotationTransform` acts if it has the `Listable` property, so

```
r[45, {1, 1}] /* N @ data
```

also works.

Comment: Thanks.  For the purposes of my understanding, what is the purpose of angle?NumericQ?

Comment: @Kuba. Thanks for pointing out the typos. I have corrected them.

Comment: @ZWei angle_?NumericQ is a pattern test which will run the function only if you pass Numeric variable for the first argumen

Comment: No need for `Map`, you can just use `r[45, {1, 1}][data]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll. I was not aware of that. I am glad to learn about it, so thanks for the comment. I have reread the the documentation article for `RotationTransform` and could not find any mention that the function it returns had the `Listable` attribute. I did find an example under `TransformFunction` that implies that it does. It would be good if the documentation for `RotationTransform` made explicit mention of this useful property.

Comment: What is `/*`? I can't find it in the doc.

Comment: @anderstood. It is [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)